# HttpContext SignOutAsync inconsistency

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity

I have a login function where the user logs in the website through their Microsoft account.

Using the HttpContext class, I am trying to sign out the user with SignOutAsync. The problem I come across is that it works when I do it in Edge, but when I try to sign out in a private window, in chrome, and in firefox, it doesn't sign me out.

```
[HttpGet("Logout")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await this.HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpGet("Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{

    return Redirect(this.homepageLink);
}
```

I have tried to different overloads of SignOutAsync, such as putting CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, and OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, expecting it to fix the problem, but that did not end up happening.

I can provide more details if I am missing any that could help fix this.

Comment: Are you trying to sign out of your main session FROM a private window?
A private window will not interact with non-private tabs, or other private tabs.

Comment: @JeffB I'm trying to sign out and be redirected to the microsoft login page, this works in regular Edge, but if I'm in a private window, it doesn't seem to log me out, and just takes me to my website homepage. Same applies to Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your setup, you need to make sure you sign out of all of the different schemas you are using. This is an example of what I use. It first deletes the cookie, and then uses the well-known functionality of OIDC to perform a global logout by redirecting to my SSO application. If you use OIDC, this works without any additional code on your client.

```
public IActionResult Logout() => SignOut("Cookies", "oidc");
```